# SQL query to full columns without defining it in Group By and optimize the Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

one contain multiple columns and test two tables have one columns.

```
    Table:  Client
Name age Benefit Id code  value
Tom  33  AA      0A 1      12
Tom  33  AB      0C 1      13
Tom  33  AA      0C 5      11
Sam  31  CC      0B 3      10
Rik  28  EE      0D 5      9

Table2: Sell
Code1
1
4

Table3: tip
Code2 
5
6
```

I want output as Name,Age, Benefit, Id and Code, which code present in both table "sell" and "tip".

```
Name Age Benefit Id code Approved
Tom   33  AA     0A  1    7
Tom   33  AA     0C  5    11
```

Code I have written as

```
------Break code-----------

Create table  #temp1 as 
select c.* from Client c inner join Sell s on c.code1 = s.code
            where Benifit= AA
           
Create table  #temp2 as 
select c.* from Client c inner join Sell s on c.code2 = s.code
            where Benifit= AA

Create table  #combine as
select ss.* ,
       ,case when ss.value > 5 then ss.value- 5 Else 0 approved
from #temp1 ss inner join #temp2 ff
     On ss.Name= ff.Name
     AND  ss.Age= ff.Age 
where Benifit= 'AA'
Group by ss.Name Age
------------------------------------------------

----Since 3 table are created with repeated logic, I have put Above code is put into one code, even thought it is not optimized ----------------

select ss.Name, ss.age
             ,case when ss.value > 5 then ss.value- 5 Else 0 approved
        from 
          (select * from Client c inner join Sell s on c.code1 = s.code
            where Benifit= AA) ss
    inner join
          (select * from Client cc inner join Tip t on cc.code2 = t.code
            where Benifit= AA) ff
     On ss.Name= ff.Name
     AND  ss.Age= ff.Age 
     Group by Name Age
```

So, I have two problem:

1. I want Benefit, Id, code and value beside Name and Age, since current query not allow to do that  as 'Group By' is used
2. I am using two select multiple inner join as below

```
a.  (select * from Client c inner join Sell s on c.code = s.code1
            where Benifit= AA) ss
  
b.  (select * from Client cc inner join Tip t on cc.code2 = t.code
            where Benifit= AA) ff
```

but I don't want my code to repeatedly use the  same code as above is repeated.

3. A new column Approved is created by subtracting 5 from Value column

Note: The output will Inner join based on "Name" and "Age" between

- Inner join of Client & Sell
- Inner join between Client & Tip

Please suggest.

Note I want Name, Age having code  in both 'Sell' and 'Tip' where Benifit= AA Although output will be from "Sell".

Comment: How do you determine the benefit and id in the result set?

Comment: i dont see `code = 1` in both `sell` and `tip` tables. It is only in `sell`. Also where `Approved` is coming from?

Comment: Approved is a new column created subtracting 5 from Value column

Comment: Yes my mistake  code1 and code2 actual name is code

Comment: Benefit and Id is the one I need in the result, so I have given it as reference. Actually the output given is my requirement, but I don't know how to get it

Comment: @Vish please provide the appropriate table structure of all the related tables. As you said in another comment there are some different fields in different tables to pull those in final result set. For this we must know the source table structure.

Comment: @Vish I'm not fixing your code so not even discussing... I would like to give you the solution according to your expectation from your given table structure. You shouldn't bother with the complex code you written just take simple solution I answered here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a query like this -

```
SELECT C.Name, C.Age, C.Benefit, C.Id, C.Code, (C.Value - 5) Approved
FROM Client C 
    INNER JOIN Sell S ON C.Code = S.Code1
    INNER JOIN Tip T ON S.Code1 = T.Code2
WHERE C.Benefit = 'AA'
```

Comment: Appriciate for the reply, but it will not work. since, First I have inner join Client and Sell to get all the Name having code present in Client and in Sell table.              Then I have to again Inner join the Client with Tip  to get the code present in Client and In Tip.  Lastly we have to Inner join the output generated from both the above Inner Join on the basis of Name, Age ( Since both are present in the output of both the innerjoin) along with the Where condiont Benefit= "AA'

Comment: My answer only based on your sample values/structure in three tables Customer, Sell, Tip as you provided in your question. From your comment here I would say the table structure with sample value you provided in your question is not correct. Please update the question and provide the appropriate table structure.

Comment: I have made the necessary changes

Comment: Sorry still your question has following table information - Client(Name, Age, Benefit,Id, Code, Value ). Sell(Code1), Tip(Code2). Is this correct information? If not correct then please update your question.

Comment: yes, it is correct. let me break the code in more detail

Comment: Vish if your table structure is correct then this answer give you the correct result as you expect - "I want output as Name,Age, Benefit, Id and Code, which code present in both table "sell" and "tip".

Name Age Benefit Id code Approved
Tom   33  AA     0A  1    7
Tom   33  AA     0C  5    11